# C# Export cert in pfx format

Tags: pki, pfx, x509certificate2

NET to export a certificate from the cert store into a `PFX` file. I'm trying to use the `X509certificate2.Export` method with the `X509ContentType.Pfx` flag set, but am unsure how to handle the returned byte array and output it correctly to file.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Judging by the date, you may have already figured this out, but all you have to do is write the returned byte array directly to a file:

```
byte[] certData = cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, "MyPassword");
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\MyCert.pfx", certData);
```